# Why do I get an OSError with my function when I load names into a Combobox from a text file?

Tags: python, combobox, oserror

```
def clock_in(): #  triggered with a button in tkinter
    employee = employee_drop_list.get() # get name selected from Combobox
    employee_drop_list.delete(0, tk.END) # delete name after button clicked

    working = "Employee Time Records\\Employees_Working.txt" # folder & file
    date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d, %I:%M %p") # date format
    filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("Week_%V_%Y") # file name prefix
    location = "Employee Time Records" # folder in same location as code
    connected = os.path.join(location, filename + "_" + employee + ".txt")

    Employee_List = "Employee Time Records\\Employee_List.txt" # list to check

    if employee not in open(working).read() and employee in open(Employee_List).read():
        with open(connected, "a") as file:
            file.write(employee + "_" + date + "_" + "Clocked In" + "\n")
            label['text'] = login_success()
            with open(working, "a") as t:
                t.write(employee + "\n")
    else:
        label['text'] = login_fail()
```

Here is the Code for how I am loading names into the Combobox. The error goes away and works perfectly if I load values to the Combobox into the code instead of loading from the text file and I don't understand why.

```
employees = []
with open("Employee Time Records\\Employee_List.txt") as listFile:
    employees = [line for line in listFile]

employee_drop_list = ttk.Combobox(frame, font=20, state="normal")
employee_drop_list['values'] = list(employees)
employee_drop_list.place(relwidth=.5, relx=.125, height=60)
```

The error I get is

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rorym\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:/Programming/PYTHON FOR WINDOWS/tkinter/MT Systems employee time clock/text_test/TimeClock.py", line 161, in <lambda>
    clock_in_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Clock In", command=lambda: clock_in())
  File "E:/Programming/PYTHON FOR WINDOWS/tkinter/MT Systems employee time clock/text_test/TimeClock.py", line 47, in clock_in
    with open(connected, "a") as file:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Employee Time Records\\Week_07_2021_Amador Espinoza\n.txt'
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback in your question.

Answer (score -1):

This could be for two reasons. One, it may be that the folder is not findable by your code. Make sure it's in the same directory as the .py file. Second, it could be because you didn't specify a mode. Try adding `, "r"` to the end of the `open` call.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I have tried them with no change in results.  I just don't seem to comprehend why it works fine when I manually load the names into the Combobox but not when I load values from a text file. Seems like the OSError should either happen both times or neither. Not just in the instance where the Combobox is populated from a text file.